# Newbie OAuth issue: Error when trying to use the PHPoAuthLib OAuth lib

Tags: oauth, twitter-oauth

I've got an issue using this OAuth lib when connecting with twitter:

https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib

I'm using the following url to connect:

http://www.myserver.com/oauth/examples/twitter.php?go=go

I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuth\Common\Http\Exception\TokenResponseException' with message 'file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized ' in /webDeploy/V2/sites/wandexBB/oauth/src/OAuth/Common/Http/Client/StreamClient.php:75 Stack trace: #0 /webDeploy/V2/sites/wandexBB/oauth/src/OAuth/OAuth1/Service/AbstractService.php(52): OAuth\Common\Http\Client\StreamClient->retrieveResponse(Object(OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri), Array, Array) #1 /webDeploy/V2/sites/wandexBB/oauth/examples/twitter.php(59): OAuth\OAuth1\Service\AbstractService->requestRequestToken() #2 {main} thrown in /webDeploy/V2/sites/wandexBB/oauth/src/OAuth/Common/Http/Client/StreamClient.php on line 75

It looks like the request body is empty.

I see in the code the following params are being used:

```
    $_GET['oauth_token'],
    $_GET['oauth_verifier'],
```

What are these params?  I see in my twitter account I have various tokens available after I created my app on twitter, is it something to do with that?

I'm lost :/  This could be the wrong approach altogether.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lib seems to have a bug relating to the twitter implementation.  Now using a different lib and got that going much more easily:

https://github.com/sudocode/ohmy-auth